# Firedac difference between Array DML and Cached updates

Tags: delphi, firedac

Simple question

what is difference between cached updates option and array DML?
I supposed that cached updates was for limit LAN round-trip but i see now Array DML feature.

What difference?

Comment: Cached updates is the way how to perform buffered changes in a single batch at a later time (the changes are buffered and can be flushed later at once). Array DML is the way how to tranfer data from client to DBMS (for DBMS' that has native support it may increase the speed quite radically). So they are different things that have different applications. If they can be combined, if you can use cached updates and those updates are then transferred to the DMBS as DML array I don't know. But that would be a different topic.

Comment: Then what difference if cached updates perform buffered chenges in single batch and array dml do "the same"?
I still do not see this difference

Comment: They are for different purposes. An example of where to use cached updates might be some detail edit dialog where the user makes some changes to the data and have the save and cancel button. When they press the save button, you flush the cached changes. Cancel will throw the changes away. DML array is just the way how you transfer many tuples to the DBMS at once.

Comment: Cached Updates are merely a sequence of INSERT, EDIT and DELETE statements in any order. Array DML is one statements (e.g. INSERT) with a sequence of data records following. Cached Updates work with every DBMS while Array DML has to be supported by the DBMS.

Comment: Maybe i wrong describe my question, Why array DML(AD) is introduced if cached updates(CU) was designed to post data to server in minimal round-trip?
May be this was wrongly designed? Data are only cached on client side and send to server packet by packet(insert by insert...)? But in CU insert, update, delete can be merged and send to server in bigger packet like AD do. Why two different option to do the same?
Maybe is really some other difference but i do not see it.
I see that is radical difference in speed(20x) - but only because CU are not optimized to be merged into bigger packets?

Comment: Cached updates saves traffic just when you e.g. insert a row and delete it in one batch (the result should then be *nothing* instead of one insert and one delete). Take it as a buffer, not as something to speed up traffic. But yes, cached updates might use array DML transfer (maybe they already do, I don't have enough recent version).